# how can i use ng2 component like react

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to angular2.in my react project, my component looks like this:

```
export const DefaultButton = (props: Props) => {
  return <button {...props}>{props.children}</button>
}

<DefaultButton>delete</DefaultButton>
```

ng2:

```
@Component({
    selector: "button-default",
    template`<button>{{text}}</button>`,
    styleUrls: ["./default.css"]
})
export class ButtonDefaultComponent {
    @Input() private text: string
}
```

can i use ng2 like this?

```
<button-default>delete</button-default>
```

Comment: Use `ng-content` https://plnkr.co/edit/31HKgs0zB8ngVlhAC38B?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui thanks~, this fixed my issue!

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers are close, but I think what you want is in the comment by @yurzui. You don't need an @Input decorated value, if all you're trying to do is pass down the word "delete" like in React. You can just use `<ng-content>`.

```
@Component({
  selector: "button-default",
  template: '
  <button>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </button>
  ',
  styleUrls: ["./default.css"]
})
export class ButtonDefaultComponent { }
```

and

`<button-default> Delete </button-default>`

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you want to have `"delete"` string inside your component as part of `text` input variable.

Your ts code is good, just change implementation of component in html:

```
<button-default [delete]="'delete'"></button-default>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Component**

```
@Component({
selector: "button-default",
template`<button>{{text}}</button>`,
styleUrls: ["./default.css"]
})

export class ButtonDefaultComponent {
   @Input("delete") private text: string
}
```

**index**

```
<button-default delete="delete"></button-default>
```

that is.